# Is my gas pedal long enough to enable heel-and-toe shifting?

Tags: shifting, braking, pedals

I've heard much and recently watched a video about performing the heel-and-toe technique.

I tried some dummy actions, with my car shut off and in neutral but it feels too difficult to successfully place my foot on both the brake and gas pedal.

Here are my pedals--is the gas pedal sufficient length to execute this?  Or is the pedal typically longer to enable the heel?

[image: Car Pedals]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Heel and Toe Pedals

[image]

I think to truly heel-and-toe drive well, you need to have a setup similar to the one in the image.  Something that's designed to do it proper.

There's some that are super cheap.

You have to consider how much it will effect your normal driving though.

This setup will prevent you from trying to bend your leg all weird to actually do it.

***To answer your question***

> Is my gas pedal long enough to enable heel-and-toe shifting?

No, but your brake pedal is to far to the left and there is very little pedal overlap.  It's not the length of your gas pedal, it it's overlapping width and placement in relation to your brake.

Comment: Once you figure out the pedals also make sure to wear the right shoes. They make a huge difference! Piloti shoes make a big difference at the track: https://piloti.com/footwear/performance.html

Answer (score 2):

Typically the gas pedal is wider on manual cars to make heal toe easier.

Heal toe shifting is not really be best name.  You use the ball of your foot under your big toe on the edge of the brake pedal and the edge of your foot near your pinky on the gas.  Remember, when you do this your brake pedal will be pressed down a bit.